# How to display the gallery image and show only that gallery related image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 gallery column which is `"Gallary 1", "Gallary 2", "Gallary 3"`. Each gallery has more than 5 images collection.

[image]

Now, What I am doing is, When the user clicked on gallery 1 then it should be displayed only gallery one image, When the user clicked on gallery 2 then it should be displayed only gallery two images and so on.

I checked on google for the plugin but I haven't found.

Now, I am using http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/ plugin

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('.lightgallery').lightGallery({
            thumbnail: false
        });
    });
```

```css
.lightgallery a img{width: 300px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/css/lightgallery.css">
<div class="lightgallery">
  <a href="http://scbb.ihbt.res.in/SCBB_dept/video_tutorial/vd/examples/images/Swan_large.jpg">
      <img src="http://scbb.ihbt.res.in/SCBB_dept/video_tutorial/vd/examples/images/Swan_large.jpg" />
  </a>

  <a href="https://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2017/11/autumn_fireball/17255671-1-eng-GB/Autumn_fireball_node_full_image_2.jpg">
      <img src="https://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2017/11/autumn_fireball/17255671-1-eng-GB/Autumn_fireball_node_full_image_2.jpg" />
  </a>
  
  <a href="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/fall-autumn-red-season_WV7Vb7u.jpg">
      <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/fall-autumn-red-season_WV7Vb7u.jpg" />
  </a>


  <a href="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/cat-1285634_960_720.png">
      <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/cat-1285634_960_720.png" />
  </a>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
```

Above snippet is working for a single gallery section because it's displaying all the images.

Any other plugin is available for my issues?

I tried some my thought that I will created like below code and using css

```
.lightgallery a{position: absolute;} all the anchor tag images will display over the first image but this is not the right way. right?

<div class="lightgallery"><!--gallary one images--></div>
<div class="lightgallery"><!--gallary two images--></div>
<div class="lightgallery"><!--gallary three images--></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop each lightgallery div and create the gallery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lightgallery').each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).lightGallery({
      thumbnail: false
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.lightgallery a img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/css/lightgallery.css">
<div class="lightgallery">
  <a href="http://scbb.ihbt.res.in/SCBB_dept/video_tutorial/vd/examples/images/Swan_large.jpg">
    <img src="http://scbb.ihbt.res.in/SCBB_dept/video_tutorial/vd/examples/images/Swan_large.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a style="display:none;" href="https://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2017/11/autumn_fireball/17255671-1-eng-GB/Autumn_fireball_node_full_image_2.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.esa.int/var/esa/storage/images/esa_multimedia/images/2017/11/autumn_fireball/17255671-1-eng-GB/Autumn_fireball_node_full_image_2.jpg" />
  </a>
  </div>
<div class="lightgallery">
  <a href="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/fall-autumn-red-season_WV7Vb7u.jpg">
    <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/fall-autumn-red-season_WV7Vb7u.jpg" />
  </a>
  </div>
<div class="lightgallery">

  <a href="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/cat-1285634_960_720.png">
    <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/cat-1285634_960_720.png" />
  </a>


</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.6.11/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's working but If I am adding more then one image in the gallery one that also displays on the screen. how can we hide them? because I need only one image

Comment: just set display:none to the images you don't want to appear, see updated snippet

Comment: That's cool!! thanks, it's working perfectly for me..upvote from my side.